# c# LINQ Dictionary of anonymous type values

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am trying to prepare a dictionary which contains `COLUMN_NAME` as Key and `{IS_NULLABLE, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH}` as value.

This is what I have done so far.

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

var dt = GetDataTable($"SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='{tableName}'");
if (dt != null)
{
    dict = dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(row => row.Field<string>(0), row => new { IS_NULLABLE = row.Field<bool>(1), DATA_TYPE = row.Field<string>(2), CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = row.Field<int>(3) });
}
```

`GetDataTable` function which not listed here, works fine and returns me a valid `System.Data.DataTable`.

Compiler throws...

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'

Question is, How do I generate an anonymous object with these properties -
 `IS_NULLABLE`, `DATA_TYPE`, `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH`?

Comment: Why you dont create a class `DbColumn` instead? Then your dictionary is a `Dictionary<string, DbColumn>`

Comment: Yes, That's easy fix. I know. But I want to achieve this using anonymous types.

Comment: Why? That's not just a fix, it's a much better approach because you can use that dictionary as field in a class or pass it as argument. You can also extend it later or provide methods. You also have compile time safety and can access the properties without having to cast them as opposed to `object`.

Comment: I don't need to extend it later. It is temporary object and I just want to check if a column confirm to data type and char limit. I don't want add one more class in my project if it is manageable using anonymous types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not return dictionary outside method you do not need to declare it.

```
    var dt = GetDataTable(@"SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='{tableName}'");
    var dict = dt?.AsEnumerable()?.ToDictionary(row => row.Field<string>(0), row => new { IS_NULLABLE = row.Field<bool>(1), DATA_TYPE = row.Field<string>(2), CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = row.Field<int>(3) });
```

you will get `Dictionary<string, anonymous type>`.

Than you can use your Type:

```
if(dict["key"].IS_NULLABLE) MessageBox.Show("yeah....");
```

Comment: Dictionary declaration was the main issue in my code. Marking this as answer since this is first answer that identified the main issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion it would be much better to create a class `DbColumn` instead. Then your dictionary is a `Dictionary<string, DbColumn>` and you can use it also as field or pass it to other methods and you don't have to cast everything everytime as with `Object`. You can also extend that class with other properties or methods.

However, if you only need this dictionary in that method it would still be better to *not* store it in a `Dictionary<string, Object>` to avoid casting.

Therefore you could use `var`:

```
var dt = GetDataTable($"SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='{tableName}'");
if (dt != null)
{
    var dict = dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(row => row.Field<string>(0), row => new { IS_NULLABLE = row.Field<bool>(1), DATA_TYPE = row.Field<string>(2), CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = row.Field<int>(3) });
    // here you can access all properties of the anonymous type without having to cast
}
```

Of course this works only if you just need to use it in the `if` which seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

You must explicitly cast your anonymous object to `object` type like this:

```
dict = dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(row => row.Field<string>(0), row => (object)new { IS_NULLABLE = row.Field<bool>(1), DATA_TYPE = row.Field<string>(2), CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = row.Field<int>(3) });
```

because otherwise compiler creates a dictionary of a different type.

Answer (score 1):

Simply cast your new anonymous object to `object`, you cannot convert a generic class from a type to another natively.

```
dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .ToDictionary(row => row.Field<string>(0),
         row => (object)new // Here, we cast the result to object, so the dictionary will actually use the type 'object' and not 'anonymous type'
             {
                 IS_NULLABLE = row.Field<bool>(1),
                 DATA_TYPE = row.Field<string>(2),
                 CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = row.Field<int>(3)
             });
```

Indeed, your `ToDictionary` call doesn't return a `Dictionary<string, object>`, but a `Dictionary<string, anonymous type>`. Even though `anonymous type` derives from `object`, the cast cannot be made with generic types (thus, with Dictionaries).

You won't be able to access your anonymous type's properties with `object` though, so you should probably use `dynamic` instead.